# Why does iTunes Match hang on Step 2?

Tags: itunes-match

iTunes Match just became available in the Netherlands and I ordered it just now. The matching process is now in step 2, but it doesn't seem to make any progress. It was at 160 of about 4000 songs, than I restarted iTunes and now it is sitting at 221. I didn't actually see the progress happen from 160 to 221. It has been sitting at the same number of songs for several hours (apart from this "jump").

<s>I also basically have the same issue on another Mac (just stuck at a different number), which mostly has the same iTunes library (but not quite).</s>Actually, this Mac has just finished. The other one refused to continue matching while this one was doing it, so everything might just be a case of extremely slow progress, or some issue with the update of the progress report.

Does someone have any idea what is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I have found this extremely elaborate post by "sapintel" on the Apple Support forums. Actually, inspecting the open files and ports as described here has shown me that iTunes is in fact opening and closing files, so it may just be a progress bar issue.

---

How to fix Step 2 and Step 3 Errors in iTunes: Music Media Formats, and Checking Firewall Blocks.

Step 1, 2, or 3 Hangs: Problems with Media Formats.
If you have heterogenous media formats in your music files, some of them will FAIL iTunes match, causing it to hang. This is a software error in iTunes match, which should mark the files as "Not eligible" instead of remaining stuck in an endless loop. These errors never occur if all the songs in the music library are unprotected AAC 256 kbps music files encoded by iTunes 10.5.1.

There are two basic ways to upgrade your song media formats to iTunes 10.5.1 AAC encoding - encode all of them at once, or do them selectively. In either method, you must delete the original version from iTunes and your file system. If you previously loaded them to iCloud, get rid of them there also.

You will be able to see a hung file in OS/X under Activity Monitor → iTunes → Inspect Process → Open Files and Ports. In Windows you will have to use standard Task Manager inspections.

In my iTunes library, I found that certain AAC (`*.m4a`) files which were encoded in before 2011 were stuck, and `*.m4p` Protected AAC files.

You may convert all files which were not encoded at 256 kbps AAC with a right-mouse click. Find them:

1) individually in iTunes as you discover them in Open Files and Ports trace, or
2) by creating a sort smart playlist that matches their pattern. For example, a playlist with bit-rate < 256k.

After converting them, you MUST delete the previous file(s) from your iTunes library, move the actual file to trash, and delete the trash. Archive the files if you wish. If any of them were already matched to iTunes Match, you must delete them there also.

After getting rid of older media formats, your Open Files and Ports window should no longer show any music file open in your iTunes library.

If you have converted your music library and Step 3 is still stuck with no file open, it is likely a Firewall problem. Check the last line in Open Files and Ports, and use the information in the last rows to check your firewall settings. The upload port is shown in this form, 192.168.1.1:53089 → 72.21.214.201:https. If you see this type of row, but nothing is being uploaded, a firewall or other issue is blocking that port.

In my case the block was created by my broadband modem settings. Check with the installation guide for your modem - typically they can be managed by a `http://` address such as `http://192.168.1.254/`. Change the firewall settings as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is nothing wrong with it. uploading 4000 at 3MBs to 6MBs is a lot of memory. If you are going through WIFI to upload it, or even almost any internet connection it will take some time. Also when uploading, progress bars are not reliable. they some times freeze and stop. It may look like its hanging, but it mostly is still working you will just need to give it sometime. The speed of your computer can affect it as well, if it's not a newer faster computer it can added to the time it will take.

Comment: It is my understanding that for any songs it can match, iTunes Match will not actually upload much at all. It may need to upload some identifying fingerprint information, but I wouldn't expect that to be the entire song. Also, no progress at all during almost an entire workday (I neglected to mention that) does make it seem like something more is going on than "slowness".