# ITunes Match will not match all songs

Tags: itunes-match

In step 2 of iTunes Match, all of my songs except one are matched (3937 of 3938) and it is stuck at step 2. Is there a way to force the final match? I'm missing artwork on my iPhone and iPad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does iTunes Match hang on Step 2?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37270/why-does-itunes-match-hang-on-step-2)

Answer (score 1):

Just wait. Sometime it can take awhile, due to the hundreds of people doing the same thing right now. Or you can restart it, if nothing else works.

Comment: I didn't mention that I left it open for about 5 hours.